# Getting if my array has a word that appears on my string C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a file with common compliments like this:

```
Hello
Hi
Hey
```

And in every line there is a new word. I got those words onto an array and now if my string has "hi", I want to know if there is "hi" in the array for example:

```
string Message = Hello people;
string[] Compliments = ReadAllLinesFromXFile();

if (message.contains(compliments)){
    do x function
}
```

this is in C# and any help I would apreciate

Comment: A simple loop over `Compliments` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using LINQ's [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
if (compliments.Any(message.Contains))
    // do something
```

This iterates over the `compliments` array and calls `message.Contains()` for each of the compliments until one of them is found in the `message` string.